# Function Resize image: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-resizing

I would like to resize all images in the first folder "path" but I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import os

path = "./home/my_directory"

for image_name in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    image_path = path+"/"+image_name
    print(image_name)
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    resize_img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

I get this error:

```
.DS_Store
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resize_images.py", line 12, in <module>
    resize_img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

I use Python 3.6 and opencv-python 4.2.0.32

Comment: You have empty images. You probably are not providing the actual path, file name or suffix properly. Check to see that you are getting the right paths. Try viewing the images before resizing.

Comment: Thank you very much, When I do  `print(img)` after `img = cv2.imread(image_path)` it list me images like below   `... 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  1   1   1]
  [  1   1   1]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  1   1   1]
  [  1   1   1]]]
IM-0526-0001.jpeg
[[[5 5 5]
 `

Comment: the error can be from version of OpenCv ?

Comment: Use cv2.imshow() to view your image and see if it is correct without doing the resize. If that works, then there is an issue in your resize command. It looks OK to me, but perhaps supply other arguments as described at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d

Comment: Yes, the error could conceivably be an issue with compatibility of OpenCV 4 with Python 3.

Comment: I installed CV2 with `pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: `.DS_Store` is not an image file.

Answer (score 0):

`imread` is not able to read empty or broken images. You are trying to apply `resize` operation on a broken/empty image. That is why it fails.
Try adding these lines after your `imread` line and before the `resize` function:

```
if image is None:
    continue
```

Answer Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242990/cv2-image-error-error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cv]