# cv2.resize() - error - OpenCV(4.2.0) - error: (-215:Assertion failed) - loop over images

Tags: python, opencv

I want to read in some images from a folder on my desktop called `no` using `open-CV::cv2.imread()`, resize the images, and then write them out to a new folder called `no_images`.

The problem's that I get an error message for `cv2.resize()`: `OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`

```
import cv2
import glob

path = 'C:/Users/jimmy/Desktop/archive/no'
image_no = 1
for file in glob.glob(path):  
    try:
        image_read = cv2.imread(str(path) + '/' + str(file) + '.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)     
        resized_image = cv2.resize(image_read, (100, 100))
        path2 = 'C:/Users/jimmy/no_images/'
        cv2.imwrite(str(path2) + str(image_no) + '.jpeg', resized_image)
        image_no += 1
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

When I try to resize just the first image (see below) called `1 no` in the `no` folder, it works fine. I therefore know for sure that at least the first image isn't corrupt, so why am I not getting ANY resized images in the `no_image` folder when I run my loop?

```
path = 'C:/Users/jimmy/Desktop/archive/no'
img = cv2.imread(str(path) + '/' + '1 no' + '.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
path2 = 'C:/Users/jimmy/no_images/'
cv2.imwrite(str(path2) + 'new1' + '.jpeg', resized_image)
```

Comment: did yoy try removing the second image fro  your list ? Did yo get the same error ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837231/function-resize-image-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-resiz

Comment: It could be that computer cannot find one of the files. imread will return None if it cannot find the file, so you could do something like `if imread is None; print('could not find file ', fname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `glob` and the construction of the image file name is wrong; as it is, only the file name `C:/Users/jimmy/Desktop/archive/no/C:/Users/jimmy/Desktop/archive/no.jpeg` is generated - one could say that's a no-no.
To generate all `.jpeg` file names in the path, set

```
path = 'C:/Users/jimmy/Desktop/archive/no/*.jpeg'
```

and then use just

```
        image_read = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```