# Why am i getting this IndexError?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have split my signature folder into train, val and test. And now I want to see two orig_train signature selected randomly and one forg_val signature. But I am getting Error.
Note: I didn't use Forged signature in training (It's the part of my research, it's not something I did by mistake)

````
#Train-Validation-Test Split
#Signatures of 4 people are used for training
#Signatures of 2 people are used for validation
#Signatures of 2 people are used for testing

orig_train, orig_val, orig_test = orig_groups[:4], orig_groups[4:6], orig_groups[6:]
forg_val, forg_test = forg_groups[:4], forg_groups[4:]```
def visualize_sample_signature():
    '''Function to randomly select a signature from train set and
    print two genuine copies and one forged copy'''
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize = (10, 10))
    k = np.random.randint(len(orig_train))
    orig_img_names = random.sample(orig_train[k], 1)
    forg_img_name = random.sample(forg_val[k], 0)
    orig_img1 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[0], 0)
    orig_img2 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[1], 0)
    forg_img = plt.imread(forg_img_name[0], 0)
    orig_img1 = cv2.resize(orig_img1, (img_w, img_h))
    orig_img2 = cv2.resize(orig_img2, (img_w, img_h))
    forg_img = cv2.resize(forg_img, (img_w, img_h))

    ax1.imshow(orig_img1, cmap = 'gray')
    ax2.imshow(orig_img2, cmap = 'gray')
    ax3.imshow(forg_img, cmap = 'gray')

    ax1.set_title('Genuine Copy')
    ax1.axis('off')
    ax2.set_title('Genuine Copy')
    ax2.axis('off')
    ax3.set_title('Forged Copy')
    ax3.axis('off')

visualize_sample_signature()
````

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-8ca6484a3a89> in <module>
----> 1 visualize_sample_signature()

<ipython-input-112-2588ee191bd7> in visualize_sample_signature()
      7     forg_img_name = random.sample(forg_val[k], 0)
      8     orig_img1 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[0], 0)
----> 9     orig_img2 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[1], 0)
     10     forg_img = plt.imread(forg_img_name[0], 0)
     11     orig_img1 = cv2.resize(orig_img1, (img_w, img_h))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling random.sample()

```
orig_img_names = random.sample(orig_train[k], 1)
```

You are only drawing one sample.

Syntax: random.sample(sequence, k)

sequence: is what you are choosing from

k: is the number of samples you are choosing

In this case you are choosing 1 sample and later in your code you are asking for the next element in orig_img_names.

```
orig_img2 = cv2.imread(orig_img_names[1], 0)
```

There is not an element at position 1; only at position 0. Therefore you get a "list index out of range."

In other words, you only have one image to choose from in orig_img_names.

Comment: Check to see what files, names and/or paths you have in orig_groups. That seems to be an issue with some previous code.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. But now I am getting another error. ```error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
``` in line number 11 mentioned above.

Comment: Resolved the path error just now. Now I am stuck with CV::Resize Error

Comment: Maybe check your working directory.You are definitely trying to resize a non-image. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242990/cv2-image-error-error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cv